# Laravel Service Provider - Access methods and properties of a class

Tags: php, laravel

I am at a crossroads and I do not know if I am missing something. I have a very simple `ServiceProvider`, in which I define the bindings and do `dependency injection` in my classes. Basically I am saying that when the interface `ExampleInterface` is required, it returns the class `MyAwesomeClassB`, but in my class `MyAwesomeClassB`, I need to access the `properties` and `methods` (instance) of the class from where it is called. I show the structure of my files.

```
<?php

class PackageServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{   
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(ExampleInterface::class, MyClassB::class);
    }
```

```
<?php

class MyClassA
{
    public $property = 'Hi';
    public $exampleInterface;

    public function __construct(ExampleInterface $exampleInterface)
    {
        $this->exampleInterface = $exampleInterface;
    }

    public function myAwesomeMethod1()
    {
        return $this->exampleInterface->doSomething();
    }

    public function myAwesomeMethod2()
    {
        return 'Hello World!';
    }
}
```

```
<?php

interface ExampleInterface
{
    public function doSomething();
}
```

```
<?php

class MyClassB implements ExampleInterface
{
    // I need to access from this class to the methods and properties of the
    // case from where it was called.
    // For example, from any method in this class, I need to access
    // property '$property' or method 'myAwesomeMethod2()' of
    // class 'MyClassA'

    public function doSomething()
    {
        // TODO: Implement doSomething() method.
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any help you could give me.

Comment: You can't access those methods from MyClassB unless it extends myClassA. `class MyClassB extends MyClassA implements ExampleInterface`

Comment: @IGP Thanks for answering my question. The truth is that that was the first thing I did, but if I do it the way you tell me, it seems to go into an infinite loop, resolving dependencies, in this case, ```ExampleInterface``` in the ```MyClassA``` case constructor. Could you check it out?

Comment: You can't do both things. Either have the interface in the constructor via DI or have classB extend classA. Can't do both.